# php cannot upload more than 50 kb attach file

Tags: php, file-upload

The problem is in `html_php` attachment mail sending form.
When I  attached file which is more than 50KB file size, it finishes uploading and it becomes error page.

How can I solve this problem??

I've changed `upload_max_file_size` to `32M` and `post_max_size` to `35M`) in my `php.ini`

But it doesn't work.

Hep me please as soon as you can.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What does the error page say?

Comment: also make sure that you are updating the correct php.ini file, you may have multiple php.ini files on your system

Comment: @Rasclatt => Error page says web page not found.

Comment: @bryant => my problem , cannot upload more than 50 KB attach file , is  OK in IE browser . But it is not OK yet Chrome. How should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Check the variable. It should be `upload_max_filesize` and not `upload_max_file_size` in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Also, if the allowed size is 32M and you are trying to upload a file which has size in Kb, then it should not be a problem.

Comment: sorry . Actually in my coding upload_max_filesize not upload_max_file_size.I mean it's only wrong in my question.i am not ok yet.any other suggestion??